# ¿Cómo posicionar un JButton en Java?

Tags: java, excel, java-swing

Agradezco los comentarios, estoy familiarizándome con la página.

He creado un boton pero necesito colocarlo en la parte superior izquierda de la pantalla, intente con el setBounds pero no me lo reposiciona.  Alguna idea para moverlo?

[image: Código]

Comment: Angel, para obtener ayuda en es.SO, por favor, incluye el codigo que has hecho hasta el momento, describe el problema y muestra el error, excepción o la traza de tu programa para que podamos entender tu problema y ayudarte más rapidamente

Comment: También intenté con      Container bot1 = getContentPane();
                bot1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(2,10,50));
                JButton boton1 = new JButton("Nuevo");
                bot1.add(boton1);       y efectivamente me funcionó, pero no como esperaba

Comment: te sugiero que esto que pones como comentario lo hagas editando tu pregunta y como te sugirió @JordiCastilla, completes tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás agregando el botón al contenedor que tiene un `FlowLayout`. En un FlowLayout los controles se organizan en forma horizontal. En este layout se empieza por colocar los controles al medio y, a medida que se van agregando más, se llena por los lados.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear otro panel en la parte superior del Frame y colocar allí el botón. Este frame puede ser `null` o puede ser igualmente un FlowLayout:

```
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 8, 5);
```

El primer parámetro indica el flujo del layout.El segundo el espacio horizontal y el último parámetro el espaciado vertical.